# Recommendations for client side master-detail view editor in MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a basic LMS, with a view for editing a `Chapter` of a course module. A `Chapter` will normally have a set of `Question` objects associated with it, and therefore the edit view for my Chapter will have a table/grid of questions. Using the basic, default view templates, the `Questions` part of my Chapter view is a table with *Edit*,*Details*, and *Delete* links for each question, and an "Add new" link to add new questions.

I need to be able to add and edit questions without going to a separate Question view, i.e. the editing questions must take place on the Chapter view, and in turn, each question may have multiple Option objects, as choices when the question is multiple choice.

While I could get involved in a long and complicated session developing some client code to do all this for me, I am hoping someone can tell me, is there anything existing I can use for this with relatively little extra development code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you’re trying to do I believe this is a relatively simple feature to program in ASP.MVC.  Don't use MVC Controls Toolkit or Telerik Controls, that's overkill for the problem as you have described. It will take you longer to wire up third party controls vs using plan old jQuery to make ajax calls to your controllers.

Based on your question, I assume your UI would look something like this...

[image: Example UI]

Use jQuery to make ajax calls to your Controller Actions. Popup a jquery modal dialog so you don't have to leave your question list page.  Get existing "possible answers" for a Question by creating html dynamically using jQuery and jsonResults from your Answer Controller.  Submit Edited "possible answers" to your controller simply following Phil Haack's 2008 blog article titled [Model Binding to a List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).  It should take an hour of work tops.  Good luck!

Comment: Very close, thanks @Beller. However, I rather want to expand answers for Question 1 instead of having a popup, but I will try and adapt what you suggest.

Comment: @ProfK I gave it a shot. :)  Let me know if have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing out of box but you can use model window which allows you to edit your existing question and you can bind jQuery event with add button which inject HTML to add rows with new question.

When you add/remove question dynamically you have to make sure to maintain the name attribute of your row so model binder can populate  all  question in your model on submit.

Comment: Here's an example of the jQuery UI [Modal Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form).

Answer (score 2):

Telerik has developed a beautiful set of [ASP.NET MVC controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx). One of them is a Grid control with Ajax editing support. Possible grid edit modes (that are also applied to new rows, that in your case represent questions) are 'in-line' and 'in-form'. The first option meets, I think, your requirement "to be able to add and edit questions without going to a separate Question view". See http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/Grid/EditingAjax for a demo.

As for the license: a commercial license is, depending on your options, quite expensive ($999) but they also have an [open source license](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/download-open-source.aspx) of which I do not know the details.

P.S. I am not a Telerik employee, I just like their products ;-)

Comment: I can't speak for the Grid control specifically, but most of the "Telerik MVC Extensions" look like paid versions of free [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) widgets. Make sure you can't find anything better (and cheaper!) before spending $1k on these.

Comment: @Jeroen, I used to use the Telerik controls back when they were still free. It's a great suite, but very expensive for us.

Comment: @ProfK, I understand and agree that it is much money. The big advantage of the Telerik controls is the level of abstraction they provide. There are some free alternatives but I don't know how 'close' to the HTML and JavaScript you want to get: jqGrid (http://www.trirand.com/blog/) and SlickGrid, the latter of which provides for row editor plugins of different types: http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html. Good luck with your search!